# Update current UIViewController UI upon tap of TabBar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to show an activity indicator when a user taps a certain TabBar item. My problem, I think, lies in the fact that the UI Main thread is frozen.

When a user taps the TabBar I prepare a big data list that takes about six seconds. I get the activity to show everywhere but when they tap the TabBar.

It seems as though the indicator is "running" because when the segued uitableviewcontroller shows, it is showing the indicator. But this is too late and dispatch doesn't seem to do anything either.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if let visibleViewCtrl = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.visibleViewController {
        // do whatever you want with your `visibleViewCtrl`
        print (String.init(describing: visibleViewCtrl.classForCoder))
        DispatchQueue.main.async{

            let aprogressView = ProgressView(Message: "Filtering...",
                                        Theme:.Dark,
                                        IsModal:true);

            visibleViewCtrl.view.addSubview(aprogressView)
            aprogressView.show()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

OK, So the problem is that it is going to a tableview controller, which tries to get rows in section almost immediatetly, which then first the fetchrequest which blocks everything as it is on the main thread.

Comment: put the indictor code in dispatchqueue.main.async { } block in target view controller

Comment: I did that: Edited my question

Comment: Add this code in view did load method of your view controller and after showing activity indicator prepare the data list.

Comment: We need to see code to understand how the data is being prepared. If you're doing that on the main queue from the viewController about to be presented, then it'll freeze the UI until it's finished and then present (showing your progress view)

Comment: dont put the dispatchqueue code in method put it in viewcontroller viewdidload which tab bar opening it

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw That is exactly what is happening. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Since you mentioned fetch request, are you using CoreData?

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw Yes

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Added a boolean:

```
 var loadData = false

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadData = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Then the delegates:

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    if loadData == false {
        return nil
    }
    return  searchFetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles

}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if loadData == false {
        return 0
    }
```

Now it will transition to the new controller immediately and thus I can now show feedback from viewWillAppear :

```
appDelegate.progressView = ProgressView(Message: "Filtering Brands", Theme:.Dark, IsModal:true);
    appDelegate.progressView!.show()
```

This will **NOT** work with programatical display

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: You can now accept your own solution. Do not put solutions in the question. Thank you.